# PostgreSQL: How to aggregate text so it show in the same row? (grouping by id)

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sum, aggregate-functions

From a group of student names, I'd like to identify which student performed which step per id.

This is the output I get:

```
id step1    step2    step3
1  Sam
1           John
2  Ana      
2           Charlie
2                     Bob
3           Alex
```

which I obtain with the code:

```
select id,
     case when step = 'A' then student_name end as "step1",
     case when step = 'B' then student_name end as "step2",
     case when step = 'C' then student_name end as "step3"
from my_table
group by id
```

This is the output I'd like to get:

```
id step1    step2    step3
1  Sam      John
2  Ana      Charlie  Bob
3           Alex
```

If the names were numbers, I'd do:

```
select id,
     sum(case when step = 'A' then student_name end) as "step1",
     sum(case when step = 'B' then student_name end) as "step2",
     sum(case when step = 'C' then student_name end) as "step3"
from my_table
group by id
```

However, this cannot be performed with text. How can I modify the query to achieve the output above?

Comment: Please show the sample input data of your table instead of the result sets of your queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   id    INTEGER  
  ,step1 VARCHAR(30) 
  ,step2 VARCHAR(30)
  ,step3 VARCHAR(30)
);
INSERT INTO mytable
(id,step1,step2,step3) VALUES 
(1,'Sam',NULL,NULL),
(1,NULL,'John',NULL),
(2,'Ana',NULL,NULL),
(2,NULL,'Charlie',NULL),
(2,NULL,NULL,'Bob'),
(3,NULL,'Alex',NULL);
```

just use `max` function

```
SELECT id,
       Max(step1) step1,
       Max(step2) step2,
       Max(step3) step3
FROM   mytable
GROUP  BY id
ORDER  BY id ASC
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6e2cf7d740938e1dca83b671665b74a8)

Comment: Instead of MAX() you could also use STRING_AGG(). That would also give you all results when you have multiple values for a single step. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=881966be264a87a858582b8b466dd131